# Print from Chrome without the print dialogs? Using Greasemonkey userscript maybe?

Tags: printing, google-chrome

We're developing a browser-based warehouse app that needs to print labels and invoices regularly.  We want to be able to print to the local printer without clicking through the the usual browser print dialogs.  Is this possible?  Possibly using a greasemonkey userscript?  We don't want to have to setup a whole CUPS printer network and deal with all that, but warehouse pickers having to click through a print dialog 1000 times a day isn't an option.

We're printing PDFs, not sure if that matters.  If we could do this another way using HTML5 or something else I'm open to course changes or other ideas here.

Comment: Is using Chrome a requirement?

Comment: Chrome or Firefox are options, but yeah we are strongly leaning towards Chrome.

Comment: The question makes it sound like this will be monitored locally. Is a local script that presses `Ctrl+P`, `Enter` an option?

Comment: Not that I'd recommend this solution, but we ended up solving this using a client-side macro language called AutoHotKey, http://www.autohotkey.com/.  The macro detects PDF popup windows that contain the phrase "autoprint" and then clicks through the print dialogs.  It was a bad idea but a hack that worked for a while.  Then a Chrome update came out that changed how PDFs are displayed, which broke the macro.  Dubious.

Comment: Zildjohn, the problem space is anything that can silently print from a browser client-side.  Chrome is not a requirement.  Keystrokes or any user interaction with print dialogs isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do if you start your chrome (v18+) with the --kiosk --kiosk-printing switches.

You can see it from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ewep-ZT64E

Comment: In version 39 of Google crhome is not working, there is another way to print directly?

Comment: I had the same problem with chrome 39. It was crashing. Upgraded chrome to Version 40.0.2214.11. And it resolved it. This feature is really cool.

Answer (score 3):

You can put a button on the form you are generating, then using embedded javascript in the pdf itself, cause printing to happen silently.

> There are various ways to print a
>   document without requiring user
>   interaction. One way is  to use the
>   doc object’s print method and set the
>   bSilent attribute to true, as shown 
>   in “Printing PDF Documents” on page 79
>   and in the following example:
>   `this.print({bUI: false, bSilent: true,
>   bShrinkToFit: true});`

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/AcroJSGuide.pdf

Take a look at the silent printing section under Print Production.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100  W10

Answer (score 0):

Here's a batch file example I've created based on the answer provided by @russenreaktor:

```
@echo off
start "Chrome" chrome --kiosk --kiosk-printing --url http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to do this with only JavaScript.

Comment: Are you sure, i think i have seen this done, ALso the preview uses a pdf and i have also read that you can fire the pef to print: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/AcroJSGuide.pdf

Comment: That is for PDF files, not for web pages.