# printing from web(PHP) to local printer POS (point-of-sale) directly

Tags: php, html, windows, web, point-of-sale

Is it possible to print from a website  directly to the printer ?
maybe if i first write the file than save it to a local folder, and after saving it would be run the printer? like printer spooling?

I printing now with web dialog ... ut would like to send it direct to the local printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you want a solution for server-side printing, right?

If it is a network-enabled printer that's connected to the server that serves the web page, you could use the [`lp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lp) Linux command. On Windows you can use the [`lpr`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731926.aspx) command.

The file to print could be generated from the web page code with [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) or [mpdf](http://mpdf1.com/manual/).

If it's not on the same network, you could set up a script on the printer network that checks an email address and sends the attachments from specific emails to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

js print function should do, but you will get the dialogue to confirm printing, this is a security measure on the browser to prevent hackers from using your printer.

You can overcome this dialogue in the browser setting.

Comment: here is a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056876/print-from-chrome-without-the-print-dialogs-using-greasemonkey-userscript-maybe

Comment: the  --kiosk --kiosk-printing